# Add attributes to outer tags of html fragments

Tags: php, dom

I try to add attributes to outer tags of html code fragments. I prepared some code, but it behaves strange.

The string that is for testing has two outer tags: div and paragraph. But only div gets the new attribute.

And the paragraphs is being moved into the div. What is wrong in the code?

Thanks

https://ideone.com/6Fu2zy

```
<?php
$html = '
<div>
    <a>
        <h1>Article 02</h1>
    </a>
    <img src="abc.jpg">
</div>
<p>
    <span>dsaf</span>
</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$x = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($x->query("/*") as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute("style", "xxxx");
}
$newHtml = $dom->saveHtml();
echo $newHtml;
```

### edit:

So I could put the nodes into `<root>` tags and then add attributes. But I did not know how to do that so I simply left outer `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

Adding attributes succeed but then I did not know how to remove outer `<html>` and `<body>` tags from the code.

I tried the same way than before but did not succeed.

https://ideone.com/6Fu2zy

```
<?php
$html = '
<div>
    <a>
        <h1>Article 02</h1>
    </a>
    <img src="abc.jpg">
</div>
<p>
    <span>dsaf</span>
</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$x = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($x->query("/html/body/*") as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute("style", "xxxx");
}
$newHtml = @$dom->saveHtml();
@$dom->loadHTML($newHtml, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$newHtml2 = @$dom->saveHtml();
echo $newHtml2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your HTML has not a root element, so `DOMDocument` convert the first element (`<div>`) to a wrapper for all other nodes.

Your:

```
<div>
    <a><h1>Article 02</h1></a>
    <img src="abc.jpg">
</div>
<p><span>dsaf</span></p>
```

loaded by `DOMDocument` become:

```
<div>
    <a><h1>Article 02</h1></a>
    <img src="abc.jpg">
    <p><span>dsaf</span></p>
</div>
```

Consequently the `/*` pattern return only one node.

Add a root element to your HTML:

```
<root>
    <div>
        <a><h1>Article 02</h1></a>
        <img src="abc.jpg">
    </div>
    <p><span>dsaf</span></p>
</root>
```

then use this path:

```
/root/*
```

After transformation, if you need to output only inner HTML, unfortunately `DOMDocument` doesn't have this feature. You can do something like this:

```
$innerHTML = ""; 
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'root' )->item(0)->childNodes as $child )
{ 
    $innerHTML .= $dom->saveHTML( $child );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. See 'edit' section in my question. So I did not know how to add <root> tags you mentioned and how to remove outer tags. The outer tags were <html> and <body>.

Comment: If you have `<body>` in your HTML you don't need to add `<root>`. Change `<root`> in above example with `<body>`. See [demo](https://ideone.com/iMRK2t)